# Boost Beast Async Server Failing with Assertion failed: (id_ != T::id) on multiple aync calls

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

Assertion failed: (id_ != T::id), function try_lock, file /usr/local/include/boost/beast/websocket/detail/stream_base.hpp, line 91.

```
       // Echoes back all received WebSocket messages
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_;
    boost::asio::strand<
            boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
    boost::beast::multi_buffer buffer_;

public:
    // Take ownership of the socket
    explicit
    session(tcp::socket socket)
            : ws_(std::move(socket))
            , strand_(ws_.get_executor())
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run()
    {
        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_accept(
                boost::asio::bind_executor(
                        strand_,
                        std::bind(
                                &session::on_accept,
                                shared_from_this(),
                                std::placeholders::_1)));
    }

    void
    on_accept(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() <<" : DO ACCEPT" << std::endl;

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "accept");

        std::ifstream ifs("tweetsample.txt");
        if(ifs.good())
        {
            auto tweet = std::string{};
            while(std::getline(ifs,tweet))
            {
                try
                {
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                    auto t = json::parse(tweet);
                    std::string tweet_text = t["text"];
                    auto n = boost::asio::buffer_copy(buffer_.prepare(tweet_text.size()), 
boost::asio::buffer(tweet_text));
                buffer_.commit(n);
                    do_write();
                }
                catch(nlohmann::detail::type_error& ex)
                {
                       std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void
    do_read()
    {
        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(
                buffer_,
                boost::asio::bind_executor(
                        strand_,
                        std::bind(
                                &session::on_read,
                                shared_from_this(),
                                std::placeholders::_1,
                                std::placeholders::_2)));
    }

    void do_write()
    {
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << "do_write" << std::endl;
        ws_.async_write(
                buffer_.data(),
                boost::asio::bind_executor(
                        strand_,
                        std::bind(
                                &session::on_write,
                                shared_from_this(),
                                std::placeholders::_1,
                                std::placeholders::_2)));
    }

    void
    on_read(
            boost::system::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        // This indicates that the session was closed
        if(ec == websocket::error::closed)
            return;

        if(ec)
            fail(ec, "read");

        std::cout << boost::beast::buffers(buffer_.data()) << std::endl;

        // Echo the message
        ws_.text(ws_.got_text());
        ws_.async_write(
                buffer_.data(),
                boost::asio::bind_executor(
                        strand_,
                        std::bind(
                                &session::on_write,
                                shared_from_this(),
                                std::placeholders::_1,
                                std::placeholders::_2)));
    }

    void
    on_write(
            boost::system::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        std::cout << "on_write" << std::endl;
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Clear the buffer
        buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());

        // Do another read
        do_read();
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Accepts incoming connections and launches the sessions
class listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<listener>
{
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    tcp::socket socket_;

public:
    listener(
            boost::asio::io_context& ioc,
            tcp::endpoint endpoint)
            : acceptor_(ioc)
            , socket_(ioc)
    {
        boost::system::error_code ec;

        // Open the acceptor
        acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "open");
            return;
        }

        // Allow address reuse
        acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "set_option");
            return;
        }

        // Bind to the server address
        acceptor_.bind(endpoint, ec);
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "bind");
            return;
        }

        // Start listening for connections
        acceptor_.listen(
                boost::asio::socket_base::max_listen_connections, ec);
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "listen");
            return;
        }
    }

    // Start accepting incoming connections
    void
    run()
    {
        if(! acceptor_.is_open())
            return;
        do_accept();
    }

    void
    do_accept()
    {

        acceptor_.async_accept(
                socket_,
                std::bind(
                        &listener::on_accept,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void
    on_accept(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
        {
            fail(ec, "accept");
        }
        else
        {
            // Create the session and run it
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->run();
        }

        // Accept another connection
        do_accept();
    }
};  


    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        auto const address = boost::asio::ip::make_address("XXX.XX.XX.X");
        auto const port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi("XXXX"));
        auto const threads = 1;

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        boost::asio::io_context ioc{threads};

        // Create and launch a listening port
        std::make_shared<listener>(ioc, tcp::endpoint{address, port})->run();

        // Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
        std::vector<std::thread> v;
        v.reserve(threads - 1);
        for(auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
            v.emplace_back(
                    [&ioc]
                    {
                        ioc.run();
                    });
        ioc.run();        
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

I am trying to Experiment with websocket ,currently when i recv the accept , i want to send all the data i read from file line by line .

Program crashes after the first line is sent .
Please Advise what m doing wrong .

Comment: Tried Increasing the Number of threads from which ioservice run is called . Still the issue persists .

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, so looking into the failed assertion I found this comment:

```
    // If this assert goes off it means you are attempting to
    // simultaneously initiate more than one of same asynchronous
    // operation, which is not allowed. For example, you must wait
    // for an async_read to complete before performing another
    // async_read.
    //
    BOOST_ASSERT(id_ != T::id);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a **concurrency problem**.
The answer is mentioned [here](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/1207#issuecomment-407121067)

> When you call websocket::stream::async_write, you must wait until the
> operation completes (your completion handler is invoked) before
> calling async_write again. This is explained here:
> https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket/notes.html#beast.using_websocket.notes.thread_safety
>
> If you want to send more than one message at a time, you need to
> implement your own write queue. An example may be found here:
> https://github.com/vinniefalco/CppCon2018/blob/8fc8528571561d2acee5c05f4b7a51861d1d496d/websocket_session.cpp#L87

In my case I used synchronous call:

```
 ws_.write(net::buffer(std::string(message)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    std::cout << "do_write" << std::endl;
    // Echo the message
    ws_.async_write(boost::asio::buffer(tweet),
                    boost::asio::bind_executor(strand_, std::bind(&session::on_write, shared_from_this(),
                                                                  std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)));
```

This does an asynchronous operation using a **local** buffer (the `tweet` argument goes out of scope before the operation will start/complete).

In the `read` side, you solved it by using `data_`, which is a member variable. You should consider a solution like that.

Comment: Thanks .. let me check that . But why a local variable going out of scope should give assertion of thread id not equal to Id . After reading some docs it says usually happens when trying to perform two concurrent  async op.  Isn't that the case here .. ?

Comment: When you use variables after their lifetime has ended, that causes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Literally anything can happen, and often surprising effects occur. You cannot reason about a program that invokes UB

Comment: Edited the Code Snippet. Tried changing the implementation to use buffer_copy to internal buffer  . Still getting the same assertion. I have a feeling its something else which is going wrong.

Comment: Does a buffer copy also will not own the content ?  i mean buffer copy does not do a deep copy ? kindly advise .

Comment: One thing which i noticed is on_write is not getting called even after writing the data , and another do write is called before it . what cab be the issue . really confused.

Comment: ["The boost::asio::buffer_copy function is used to copy bytes from a source buffer (or buffer sequence) to a target buffer (or buffer sequence)."](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer_copy.html)